# ConcurrentHashMap and changing it value by multiply threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, concurrenthashmap

I got the following scenarios:

Get the inputList:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, LinkedList<jobs>> inputList = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

I have two threads: Writer and Reader;

The thread Writer might add entry:

```
for (...){  // line 1
    if (!inputList.containsKey(jobListKey)) {    //line 2
        inputList.put(jobListKey, new LinkedList<jobs>());  //  LinkedList<jobs>  aka jobList   line 3
    } //  line 4
    inputList.get(jobListKey).addLast(new job(jobid)));  //line 5
}
```

The Reader thread is processing this and removed from the inputList

```
for (Iterator<Entry<String, LinkedList<jobs>>> it = inputList.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(){  //line 7
      synchronized(processList) {  //line 8     
             if (!processList.contains(entry.getKey())) {    //line 9   
                LinkedList<jobs> jobList  = entry.getValue();   //line 9a
                doProcess(jobList);  //line 10    

                it.remove();  //line 12
             }
        } 
 }
```

The problem that I have (order by time sequence):

1. *line (3)* The Writer did not find jobListKey so it created new(empty) `LinkedList<jobs>` (jobList) and put into inputList;
2. *line (8)* Reader finding new jobListKey while iteration  get `LinkedList<jobs>` (it is *empty* at this point ) and start processing, because it's empty the process failed
3. *line (5)* inputList get latest entry add new Job to the `LinkedList<jobs>` (jobList)
4. *line (12)* jobsList being removed.

There are three potential problems:

1. while  Reader is processing Joblist it might be still empty.
2. while  Reader is processing Joblist the Writer might add more new jobs(jobbid) in line 5
3. After the Reader is done with the *(line 11)* Writer might add new job as well  *(in line 5)* and this job will not be processed and missed

I have attempted to put synchronize in the Writer:

```
synchronized(inputList) {
    if (!inputList.containsKey(jobListKey)) {    //line 2
        inputList.put(jobListKey, new LinkedList<jobs>());  //  
               LinkedList<jobs>  aka jobList   line 3
    } //  line 4
    inputList.get(jobListKey).addLast(new job(jobid)));  //line 5
}
```

Unfortunately it did not work with jobList.

**Question:** How can I make sure that the LinkedList object created in line 3 will be synchronized/is thread safe?

Comment: In `Writer`, use `compute` so that these operations can be atomic.

Comment: Use the ```Deque``` class instead of LinkedList, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Deque.html. But that will only solve half of the issue. To ensure that the reader does not process input too early you would need to make sure that the reader runs only after the whole input has been collected. You would need to synchronize both parts on the same object (e.g. inputList) to ensure that they never run at the same time.

Comment: Your Reader thread code is hard to understand because it uses invalid syntax and a variable you haven't declared. Please can you improve it? (And drop the line numbers. They are annoying when copying; just add `//` comments on the small number of lines you need to highlight).

Comment: Thanks all,  tried to improve the code ,  Stefan , i have attempt to add synchronize in  Writer on inputList  the  but it did not help... and there are two different objects inputList  and processList.

Comment: The question  is still there:   how can i "lock" the  jobList instance  so Writer cannot  add new entry after jobList instance start being processed? Is there any mechanizm?